# Drupal 8, default value of a 'managed file' field

Tags: drupal-forms, drupal-8

I created an edit custom form (of a node) via a custom module. From this form, I have a "managed file" field (for one picture) and I set his default value to a fid;
However, when my form is rendered, the "managed file" field doesn't show the image ratached. I don't understand why :/

My code :

```
$form['project']['image'] = array(
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#title' => t('Image'),
  '#default_value' => 10, //Set 10 for the test, the fid "10" exist, I checked
);
```

My form rendered:

[[image]]

As you see, no image is loaded whereas the default_value is set to an existing fid (10)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qABrg.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

To render the existing image, please use the below code

```
$form['project']['image'] = array( 
  '#type' => 'managed_file', 
  '#title' => t('Image'), 
  '#default_value' => array(10), 
);
```

You need to give the fid in array format.